# Помощь в написании Javascript функции в Ocstore

Tags: php, javascript, функции, opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вообщем есть проблема с функцией addModule();
Я начинающий разработчик PHP и яваскрипта практически не знаю. Мне необходимо реализовать модуль по типу баннера и рекомендуемых товаров. Вот код функции addModule мной немного модифицированный. Подскажите как реализовать функцию полноценно чтобы добавлялись все необходимые поля.

На картинке примерно показано как работает эта функция. При нажатии "добавить модуль" появляется поле №2 без автокомплита. Как переписать функцию чтобы автокомплит заработал и сохраняло значения при выборе товара?

```html
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var module_row = <?php echo $module_row; ?>;
function addModule() {  
  html  = '<tbody id="module-row' + module_row + '">';
  html += '  <tr>';
  html += '   <td class="left"><input type="text" id="stark<?php echo $module_row; ?>"/><div id="featured-stark<?php echo $module_row; ?>" class="scrollbox"></div><?php $class = "odd"; ?><?php foreach ($module["names"] as $id =>  $product_name) { ?> <?php $class = ($class == "even" ? "odd" : "even"); ?><input type="hidden" name="stark_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][stark_ids][]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><?php } ?>'  
  html += '    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][width]" value="" size="3" /> <input type="text" name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][height]" value="" size="3" /></td>';
  html += '    <td class="left"><select name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][layout_id]">';
  <?php foreach ($layouts as $layout) { ?>
  html += '      <option value="<?php echo $layout['layout_id']; ?>"><?php echo addslashes($layout['name']); ?></option>';
  <?php } ?>
  html += '    </select></td>';
  html += '    <td class="left"><select name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][position]">';
  html += '      <option value="content_top"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>';
  html += '      <option value="content_bottom"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>';
  html += '      <option value="column_left"><?php echo $text_column_left; ?></option>';
  html += '      <option value="column_right"><?php echo $text_column_right; ?></option>';
  html += '    </select></td>';
  html += '    <td class="left"><select name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][status]">';
    html += '      <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>';
    html += '      <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>';
    html += '    </select></td>';
  html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="stark_module[' + module_row + '][sort_order]" value="" size="3" /></td>';
  html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#module-row' + module_row + '\').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>';
  html += '  </tr>';
  html += '</tbody>';
  
  $('#module tfoot').before(html);
  
  module_row++;
}
//--></script>
```

Comment: Что в переменной `$module_row`? Во первых, выстраивая новую ячейку таблицы, вы присваиваете ей как и последующим, если можно делать это много раз, одинаковый идентификатор: `...id="stark<?php echo $module_row; ?>"...`, `<div id="featured-stark<?php echo $module_row; ?>"...` и так далее...